# OCR on images using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I am a newbie to computer vision, image processing and OCR.  As a part of task, i need to perform the OCR on attached emails.  However, the problem is ROI is not constant in all images.  For example, in all images we need to extract the information related with patient Yadav.

This needs to be achieved in Python and OpenCV. Please help.  I have already tried the approach as given below:

1. Change DPI
2. Grayscale
3. Binarize
4. However, facing the problem with layout or zone analysis.

Thanks for help.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: "Write my code for me" is not a question. You should just start writing code and then come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: Dear jdv....................my point where to start from if i need to write the code.  i am should i focus on the area of ROI from start or later.  If i need to start to focus on ROI then how...what is the way.  as there many ROIs in this area.

Comment: This site is not a "design my code for me" service. No one will do it for you. You need a tutorial or guide of some sort, which you can search for on the web. e,g: "OpenCV ROI example"

Comment: BTW, I _really_ hope this data you are showing is dummy data...

Comment: yes.....it is a dummy data

Comment: also...i am not asking to write the code...but what i am requesting is to help me understand the approach as to where to start from.

Comment: Start at the beginning. Work through a tutorial or demo example and get started figuring it out. SO is not a place for turorials. Get far enough so you have specific questions about specific code you have written, in which case (by all means) ask those questions here. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the computer vision world.

I think you're not understanding your problem well enough. Just trying something and check whether it work will never work.

At first read how tesseract (OCR engine) do to improve their accuracy at https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality

Ok, then what make OCR do not work on your data. As you can see your data is clean, and there is nearly none of noise. So it is the border of printed email (as "ROI" in your question) does not correctly line up.

[image]

So have can we make the ROI line up correctly . we could use some perspective transformation. i took an example from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/

[image]

So how can we perform perspective transformation. We have to find the 4 corners of the ROI and move it back to corners of the image. To find 4 corner of the ROI you could find some contours .

So here the summary, here is the steps.

```
1. Find the ROI (white color) using color segmentation
2. Find the contour which cover the ROI
3. Find 4 corners of the ROI's contour
4. Apply perspective transform
5. Run tesseract on transformed image
```

Hope that help